# My create-controller not updating db, with dropdownlist and foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, foreign-keys

I'm using no modelview or repository, following a tutorial i found on asp.net
The dropdownlist works fine, but when I hit create, the if (ModelState.IsValid) fails and returns me to the create screen, with no error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("parentGenre", ViewBag.genreId as SelectList)
```

create controller:

```
ViewBag.genreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "genreId", "genreName");
```

part of the movie table:

```
public virtual Genres parentGenre { get; set; }
```

part of the genre table:

```
[Key]
public int genreId { get; set; }
[StringLength(25)]
public String genreName { get; set; }
public ICollection<Movies> movies { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

At a guess either genreName is greater than 25 characters or the genreId doesn't have a value.

If you take a look at the ModelStateDictionary Errors collection you should be able to the see the problem.

Add `Html.ValidationSummary()` to your view and it will tell you why IsVaild is false,

Comment: genreName length is fine, not so sure about the Id...when I used Summary, it said I needed to supply a genre.  I'm assuming I'm not getting it the id properly.  How important is it to supply the "value=" and "text=" when creating it with the new SelectListItem in the controller?

Comment: That's the problem then just provide a value in the dropdown for the genreId and it will work.